# How can we highlight cells in R shiny when we use the replace button?

Tags: shiny

The code below reads a CSV file and displays the Datatable in the Main panel. The field in 'Column to search' is automatically detected. I've created a field named 'Replace' and a field called 'by' that can be used to replace certain values in a column's cell.

I want to highlight that cell in any colour, preferably orange, wherever the values are replaced.

Could someone please explain how I can do this in R shiny?

**CSV**

```
ID  Type  Category    values
21  A1     B1          030,066,008,030,066,008
22  C1     D1          020,030,075,080,095,100
23  E1     F1          030,085,095,060,201,030
```

**Expected Output:**

If I change 030 to 100 in the columns 'values,' I want that cell (in column Values and Row 2) to be coloured.

**code**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      selectInput("col", "Column to search:", NULL),
      textInput("old", "Replace:"),
      textInput("new", "By:"),
      actionButton("replace", "Replace!"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    # validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    my_data(read.csv2(file$datapath, header = input$header))
    updateSelectInput(session, "col", choices = names(my_data()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    req(input$col)
    dat <- req(my_data())
    traf <- if (is.numeric(dat[[input$col]])) as.numeric else identity

    my_data(dat %>%
              mutate(!!rlang::sym(input$col) := 
                       stringr::str_replace_all(!!rlang::sym(input$col),
                               input$old,
                               input$new) %>% 
                       traf()))
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(
    req(my_data())
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you want that the rows stay coloured when another edit in the same column or in another column occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of a possible workaround that consists in using `DT::formatStyle()` to color each modified cell. One drawback of using this approach is that the csv imported will have twice as many columns (because i will need them to tell `formatStyle()` in which cells it has to add colors). However, the additional cols can be hidden so they don't appear displayed, but they will be present in the object passed to `datatable`. The additional columns are required if the cells need to **stay** colored after each edit, if that's not the case, then one extra column will suffice. Notice that the good news is that only `R` code is used here.

The first step will be to create the additional columns, so after the .csv file is read into reactive `my_data()`:

```
    #create (n = number of columns) reactive values.
    nms  <- vector('list', ncol(my_data())) %>% set_names(names(my_data()))
    ccol <<- exec("reactiveValues", !!!nms) 
    
    #pre-allocate all the columns that we're going to use.
    my_data(map_dfc(names(ccol), ~transmute(my_data(), 'orange_{.x}' := 0)) %>% {bind_cols(my_data(), .)})
```

Now, each time a column is modified somewhere, the corresponding orange_colname will contain a boolean indicated if a modification took place.

```
    ccol[[input$col]] <- str_detect(dat[[input$col]], input$old)
    
    my_data(my_data() %>%
              mutate('orange_{input$col}' := ccol[[input$col]]))
```

finally, we render the table using `datatable()`'s `option` argument to hide the extra cols, and then use a for loop to add the colors in each column. I need to use a loop here because the app can import any table really as long it is a data frame.

```
Dtable <- 
  datatable(my_data(),
            options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = (ncol(my_data())):((ncol(my_data()) / 2) + 1) )))) 

walk(names(ccol), ~ { Dtable <<- Dtable %>%  formatStyle(..1, str_glue("orange_{.x}"),
                                                         backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1), c("orange"))) })

Dtable
```

App:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      selectInput("col", "Column to search:", NULL),
      textInput("old", "Replace:"),
      textInput("new", "By:"),
      actionButton("replace", "Replace!"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  last_coloured <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    # validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    my_data(read_csv(file$datapath))
    updateSelectInput(session, "col", choices = names(my_data()))
    
    #create (n = number of columns) reactive values.
    nms  <- vector('list', ncol(my_data())) %>% set_names(names(my_data()))
    ccol <<- exec("reactiveValues", !!!nms) 
    
    #pre-allocate all the columns that we're going to use.
    my_data(map_dfc(names(ccol), ~transmute(my_data(), 'orange_{.x}' := 0)) %>% {bind_cols(my_data(), .)})
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    req(input$col)
    dat <- req(my_data())
    traf <- if (is.numeric(dat[[input$col]])) as.numeric else identity
    
    my_data(dat %>%
              mutate(!!rlang::sym(input$col) :=
                       stringr::str_replace_all(
                         !!rlang::sym(input$col),
                         input$old,
                         input$new
                       ) %>%
                       traf()))
    
    # also i would like to know which rows are modified
    
    ccol[[input$col]] <- str_detect(dat[[input$col]], input$old)
    
    my_data(my_data() %>%
              mutate('orange_{input$col}' := ccol[[input$col]]))
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    req(my_data())

      Dtable <- 
        datatable(my_data(),
                  options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = (ncol(my_data())):((ncol(my_data()) / 2) + 1) )))) 
      
      walk(names(ccol), ~ { Dtable <<- Dtable %>%  formatStyle(..1, str_glue("orange_{.x}"),
                                                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1), c("orange"))) })
      
      Dtable
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, everything is working as expected. Thank you for putting up the effort to provide me with the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I used the parameter `selection` from `renderDT()`. After changing `my_data()`, you can compare which positions were changed in relation with `dat` (where you stored the unchanged data.frame) and then pass them as coordinates to the `selection` parameter

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  positions <- reactiveVal(NULL) ## here we'll save positions of changed cells
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    # validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    my_data(read.csv2(file$datapath, sep = ",", header = input$header))
    updateSelectInput(session, "col", choices = names(my_data()))
  })
  

  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    req(input$col, my_data())
    dat<- my_data()
    traf <- if (is.numeric(dat[[input$col]])) as.numeric else identity

    my_data(dat %>%
              mutate(!!rlang::sym(input$col) := 
                       stringr::str_replace_all(!!rlang::sym(input$col),
                                                input$old,
                                                input$new) %>% 
                       traf()))
    
    positions(which(dat != my_data(), arr.ind = T)) # this is where new
                                                    # values positions are stored

  })

  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    req(my_data())
  }, selection=list(mode="single",##### this argument let you select a cell
                    target="cell",
                    selected = positions()))
  
}
```

If you set `input$old` to "030", all cells will be selected, since "030" is present in all 3 cells. But if you do it with "066", you'll see only the first cell of "values" will be highlighted

Comment: The replaced values are highlighted, however it vanishes soon I select/click on any cell.

Comment: So instead of being selected, you want to change the color background, for example? Like a css change?

Comment: @Paboart, You are correct.